# Вложился в выпускной. Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"..но я уже вложился в школьный выпускной..."(Подразумеваю, что сдал много денег)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как разговорный вариант - почему нет? Вложил средства = вложился. Но если это не бытовой разговор, лучше употребить литературное "вложил средства", "внёс средства", "сделал взнос" и т.д.